# Which X Window system is installed on my server that would work with Xming

Tags: linux, unix, xorg, x-server, x11-forwarding

I would like to use Xming to connect a server and managed to get it to work. I am now trying to get it to connect to a different server but i am not sure which X Window system is installed. I tried it through putty and i get the following error/warning:

`/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin> jvisualvm`
`/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/nbexec: WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set`

I have previously used a windows BAT script to launch XWindows - Shown below:

```
@echo off
SET LOCAL_HOST=localhost
SET PATH=C:\wresourcex\bin\Xming

SET REMOTE_HOST=%1
SET SCREEN=%2

REM Default to archie with screen 1
if "%1"=="" SET REMOTE_HOST=MySever.com
if "%2"=="" SET SCREEN=0

SET DISPLAY=%LOCAL_HOST%:%SCREEN%.0

REM For XDM logon just run this line
REM run Xming -query %REMOTE_HOST% -lesspointer -emulate3buttons

REM For SSH Tunneling use these 2 lines
rem run Xming :%SCREEN% -lesspointer -notrayicon -emulate3buttons
run plink -ssh -X %REMOTE_HOST% /usr/dt/bin/Xsession

REM Use this if want Gnome instead
rem run plink -ssh -X %REMOTE_HOST% /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

The above works in one server but not on the one i am using now. I have looked at both the /usr/dt/bin/ and /usr/bin folders and both program (referred to in the script) do not exist in those locations. I am guessing that i need to use a different program but how do i know which "Xwindow" program is installed on the server i want to connect to or does it matter?

Note - I do not have admin access on the server so cannot install anything.

Thanks